# Making a specific Graph with the use of R

Tags: r, graph

With the help of the Monte Carlo method I need to determine the value of Pi.
For so far I have a code that gives me Pi by a random value of the radius of the circle between 0.1 and 1. Next thing that I have to do is to plot the variable radius against the number that is found for Pi, as i tried to describe below

```
     |
   Pi|~~~~~~~~~~~~    <- values
     |
     |______________  
     0.1     R      1
```

```
library("plotrix")
n = 400
z = runif(1, 0.1, 1)
R= z
x = runif(n, -R, R)
y = runif(n, -R, R)
plot(x, y, asp = 1, xlim = c(-1, 1))
#draw a square
rect( -R, -R, R, R)
#draw a circle 
draw.circle(0, 0, R, nv = 1000, border = NULL, col = NA, lty = 1, lwd = 1)
#
#test if points are in the circle (Pin=points in circle)
pin = sum(ifelse(sqrt(x^2 + y^2 <= R^2), 1, 0))
#pi is given by (4*n in circle/n total)
  4 * pin/n
plot(z, 4 * pin/n)
```

With this code, I can make 1 point in the whole graph. What I'm looking for is to have like 100 points on the graph. So 'easily' said, let the code determine 100 pi values by different R's and plot these in one graph.
Is this possible? I've been looking for the answer for two days, but I'm not making any progress so far.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about making the calculation into a function, and running it a hundred times? Once you have the values, you can then plot them all together. The same thing can be done using a for-loop.

Here's an example. Let's create a function ppi first:

```
ppi<-function(N=1000) {
    n = N
    z = runif(1, 0.1, 1)
    R= z
    x = runif(n, -R, R)
    y = runif(n, -R, R)
    pin = sum(ifelse(sqrt(x^2 + y^2 <= R^2), 1, 0))
    return(c(z, n, pin))
}
```

You can then run that 100 times (see `replicate()`), and then plot the results using some plotting function.